# Is Mackeeper scam/malware? Please give me advice!

Tags: macos, mac

I'm not very computer literate, so I need some help with my computer and thought the application will help me to remove the duplicates and other unwanted things from the hard drive. However, I saw many negative reviews on the Net. I'm very frustrated. Thank you!

Answer (score -7, accepted):

After doing some research on the topic, I can say MacKeeper is legit. Even though many people don’t like the app as it is heavily marketed, there’re several millions of real active users. 
Their feedback is available here:
https://www.trustpilot.com/review/mackeeper.com

The developer of the app, Kromtech, has a number of other apps on the market, including Memory Keeper, which can be found on the App Store, so it is acknowledged by Apple.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memorykeeper/id689992800?mt=12

According to the info found on the official website, MacKeeper can help you to remove the files you want from your computer.

You are welcome!

Comment: I sincerely hope I'm wrong, but this sounds like a set-up, sockpuppet, Q&A exchange.

Comment: @jer-el I don't think so based on Nick Green's participation in other topics, just misinformed. Strange though accepting such a low-rated answer.

Comment: Thank you @JMY1000. I'm glad to get a little more context.

Answer (score 9):

**Depending on where you got it from, it's either malware or just useless. You should uninstall it either way.**

Although the official version of MacKeeper isn't directly harmful usually and doesn't qualify as typical malware, it doesn't do any good–and in some cases, may actually remove files it shouldn't. There are much better apps for "cleaning" your computer, like [CleanMyMac 3](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac), [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org), [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), etc. They've also been the subject of [data leaks](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3wq9fc/massive_data_breach/?) and [class-action lawsuits](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2919292/apple-security-program-mackeeper-celebrates-difficult-birthday.html). Many versions are not clean copies, with other viruses of various sorts loaded on disguised as part of MacKeeper.

So how to get rid of it? [MacWorld has a pretty good guide](http://www.macworld.com/article/2861435/software-utilities/how-to-uninstall-mackeeper-from-your-mac.html), but I'll skip some of it in favor of just downloading [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org) and letting it do it's job in case some other stuff got installed as well. Let it run, and once it's done, if there are any remaining traces, quit any relevant process and move them to the trash and empty said trash.

Overall, it's a good idea not to click on advertisements if you don't understand entirely what they're advertising. [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) is a good content blocker that does a good job blocking ads if you'd like to refrain from accidentally reinstalling it in the future. Still, nothing is guaranteed: make sure you know what you're clicking on and giving access to before you do.

Comment: I won't use uBlock because they are part of the problem; see https://www.troyhunt.com/ad-blockers-are-part-of-the-problem/  [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) is much better and doesn't use the questionable practices of uBlock.